# Can I get a server's server time by querying its HTTP header?

Tags: objective-c, http, networking

Say, can I get `http://www.google.com` 's server time?

How to do that in ObjC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure:

```
NSURLRequest *rq = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:rq queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *resp, NSData *data, NSError *err) {
    NSDictionary *headers = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)resp allHeaderFields];
    NSString *dateString = [headers objectForKey:@"Date"];
    NSLog(@"Google Server Date: %@", dateString);
}];
```

Comment: Does the "Date" field always presents in the headers?

Comment: @smilingpoplar I don't know, I'm not an HTTP standards freak, but in the particular case of Google (which you are interested in), it's there.

Comment: It's a required header from any origin server, except in a few cases (1XX responses and some 5XX).

Comment: @Kylar Here comes the HTTP standards freak! =P Thanks, it's useful, I haven't known it.

Comment: @smilingpoplar asked, so I answered :)

Comment: The "Date" field is also part of the official HTTP protocol spec, it's purpose though is for cache control, but I guess you can use it as the server time.
https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.0/spec.html